# Ubuntu 14.10 Wifi drops to 0 B/s

Tags: networking, wireless, 14.10, iwlwifi

I have Ubuntu 14.10 installed and if I connect to a network (with Wifi) first everything works great with good transferring rates. However after some time (few minutes, sometimes longer) the connection drops to a transfer rate of 0 B/s, also ping doesn't work but I remain connected.
After a disconnect and a reconnect this is solved for again some few minutes.

Especially when I'm using a web installer which downloads some files this happens really fast. Browsing sometimes works very long.
I ran a Wifi script at the not-working state, output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10832694/

I couldn't find any error in `dmesg`.

EDIT: also updated the firmware of iwlwifi now, which doesn't solve the problem.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I would change the encryption on the wifi router to WPA2-AES or WPA2 only and see if it improves. You are currently using TKIP and that usually causes issues with Ubuntu

Comment: Ok I will test this as soon as I can but at the moment I'm testing without a WLAN-Repeater which also looks promising.